# How can i save or retrieve data according to time(sequence)

Tags: android, firebase

if i saved two users data and now i want to retrieve users it must be in sequence that newest data or user on the top
i tried and explored but not found concept about it
as data is retrieved from data base

````
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Users users = userSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        usersList.add(users);

                    }
                    mAdapter = new Adapter_All_Users(usersList);
                    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                }

            }  ```
it just set data in recycleview as random
````

Comment: Please show your database structure in firebase and how you insert your data, are you using `push()` when saving data ?

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3rwd.png here it is

Comment: You can use `ref.orderByKey()`

Answer (score 1):

You should have a date field, so you will be able to get data like:

```
ref.orderByChild("date")
```

Note: it will always come in ascending order

More info : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.sort(usersList);` before adding it to adapter

And inside your `Class` (of list type) Override `compareTo()` method where you just
`return obj.getDate().compareTo(this.getDate());` (or reversed, I don't remember).
Compiler will know how to compare those dates even if it is a String format (not Date), you just have to tell it which field should be compared while sorting

Comment: Sorting fiirebase collection on client side after it was retrieved will take a lot of time if the collection is huge, or will make you to call sort multiple times if collection uses pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can use also use `ref.orderByKey().AddValueEvent` since you have generated a unique key. This key serve as the time stamp of the data